# Windows backup takes more space than original data on disk

Tags: backup, windows, disk-space-utilization

Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012 (and SharePoint 2013 installed).

Within VM:
Disk C -> Properties -> Used Space 130GB.
Start Windows Backup -> Progress -> "Local disk (C:) data transferred *x*GB of 255GB"

Resulting backup is close to 300GB in size.

Tried restoring from it - same result. 130 taken. Next backup takes 300.

Any idea what are those other 150+ GB?

Comment: Could you detail how you configured Windows Backup? It sounds like you might have incremental/differential backups happening, where instead of just a snapshot in time of your drive, you're getting different versions of the same file that was changed since last backup. This would account for the discrepancy.

Comment: You know Windows Backup. Not much to configure. Just Full Server Backup. Dedicated disk (last time tried - emptied it in advance). Performance settings: "Normal backup performance". Full backup (not Copy backup). I think that's all that can be configured.

Comment: Do check for file system issues on the source file system by running `chkdsk`. Also, do you happen to have data de-duplication enabled or a significant amount of NTFS-compressed data?

Comment: chkdsk: "Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required."

Comment: Compressed are SharePoint logs, and they are huge in size but very small on disk. Seems to be the reason - I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Removing NTFS compressed logs fixed the problem.